# Scala default parameters from other parameters

Tags: scala

I'm trying to do something like the following, and the compiler is not happy...

```
def foo(db: Database = ctx.defaultDB)(implicit ctx: Context)
```

That is, if db isn't specified, use ctx to look up the default.  The compiler didn't like this version so I tried this:

```
def foo(ctx: Context, db: Database = ctx.defaultDB)
```

Compiler didn't like that either...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many limitations on default parameter values.

I suggest overloading:

```
def foo(db: Database)(implicit ctx: Context) = ...

def foo(implicit ctx: Context): Type = foo(ctx.defaultDB)(ctx)
```

I'm not sure what the exact requirement is, but my quick testing suggests you have to make the return type on the 2nd overload explicit.

Comment: All good answers here, but this one is the cleanest from the caller's perspective, and that's what I'm after.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def foo(dbOption: Option[Database] = None)(implicit ctx: Context) {
  val db = dbOption.getOrElse(ctx.defaultDB)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
def foo(ctx:Context)(db:Database = ctx.defaultDB )
```

Of course, it isn't implicit. You might be able to make it implicit with a trick like this:

```
def foo(implicit ctx:Context) = {
  class XXX {
    def apply(db:Database = ctx.defaultDB) = ...
  }
  new XXX(ctx)
}
```

However, that won't work like you expect, because `foo(x)` will pass `x` as the implicit, and `foo()(x)` will give an error. Only `foo.apply(x)` will work, and that sucks.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
def foo(db: Database = implicitly[Context].defaultDB) = ???
```